# What should I call algorithms with non-linear non-constant time?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, terminology, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I am writing a paper in which I want to refer to a group of algorithms. Some of these algorithms are of complexity `O(NlogN)`, and some of the are more complex (e.g polynomial-time) and I want to refer to them all in one term. Is there any common term to use in such a situation?

`linearithmic` refers to `O(NLOGN)` algorithms and it's narrower than what I'm looking for. I don't think of `non-linear` as a good term to use here. If it is, then correct me please.

my sentence:

> In such a setting, state-of-the-art community-detection algorithms does not scale well. To reduce the running time of these XYZ algorithms, each sub-graph is partitioned into chunks.

I want to change `XYZ' in the above, to what I am asking for.

Comment: I have seen the term “super-linear” used before, but I’m not sure if that’s the well accepted term.

Comment: [Linearithmic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/linearithmic#Adjective) commonly refers to $n \log n$ time.

Comment: @BryceKille "super-linear" just means "anything more than linear".

Comment: @David Richerby Could you please clarify this being a duplicate? From the OP's last sentence I would say it is quite clear "linearithmic" is a much narrower term than what they are looking for.

Comment: @dkaeae The question asks for a term for algorithms with a running time of $n\log n$.

Comment: No @David Richerby ! I am asking for a term referring to multiple algorithms with some of them being `O(nlogn)` and some of the being polynomial-time or beyond that. In my sentence I am talking about not a single algorithm but multiple algorithms. They're not all `linearithmic` and I dont think it's a duplicate...

Comment: I can't imagine that there's a term for such a specific combination of situations. Why would a language have that?

Comment: @DavidRicherby What ameerosein is trying to say is that they are looking for a term encompassing not only running times of O(n log n) but also O(n^2), O(n^3), or even greater than that. I believe that makes it pretty clear "linearithmic" is not the appropriate term.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you cant think of any, then you can add an answer and say there is not term describing it. That does not mean it's a duplicated question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Bryce Kille in the comments, **superlinear** is what you are looking for. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlinear):

> 2. (mathematics) Describing a function that eventually grows faster than any linear one

(By the way, the first phrase in your question strikes me as rather odd: "[...] I want to refer to a group of algorithms that are mostly polynomial-time, but one of them is of complexity $O(N \log N)$." Do you simply mean "linear" instead of "polynomial-time"?)

Comment: OK, but "superlinear", as you say, just means "anything bigger than linear". The function $2^{2^{2^n}}$ is superlinear, so saying that your algorithm has "superlinear" running time gives very little information, and is usually a negative statement. "Subquadratic" is probably more appropriate, since it gives an upper bound.

Comment: "Subquadratic" misses the point because the OP asks for "faster than linear". If polynomial-time is not clear from the context, it can be mentioned explicitly, as Peter Taylor writes in the other answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby as my example says, I am not trying to provide and upper bound but I am trying to say that all the available algorithms out there are more complex and takes longer theoretically, that is to say a lower bound. Maybe my question is not clear enough so I appreciate if you edit it if you think you can make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the other answers, you can also say $\omega(n)$ and people *should* know what you mean, but often won't.

Comment: Right. They often won't.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to refer to a group of algorithms that are mostly polynomial-time, but one of them is of complexity `O(NlogN)`. Is there any common term to use in such a situation?

Yes: *polynomial*. Note that $O(N \lg N) \subset O(N^2)$.

> I am trying to mention that these algorithms' running time grow faster than linear.

That makes them *superlinear*. If you want to be explicit about the fact that you're talking about the intersection you could say *superlinear polynomial*.

Comment: Be careful. Although an algorithm that runs in time $\Theta(n\log n)$ is in polynomial time, the function $n\log n$ is not itself a polynomial and shouldn't be described as one.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think so... as @DavidRicherby mentioned, theyr shouldn't be described this way. This way you can any linear-time algorithm exponential... but you're not conveying information!